# Netbeans8.1 does not hightlight current program counter when debugging with weblogic

Tags: netbeans, weblogic, remote-debugging

I'm using netbeans 8.1 to debug a web app which is deployed on weblogic server(on localhost).  However, there is no high light for the current program counter so I can't know where it's stopped.  If I debug a local app, it displays correctly.

Debuggin a local app:
[image: Debugging a local app]

Debugging a remote web app which is stopped at the break point:
[image: Debugging a remote web app]

Edit:
I found this [Bug 188844 - Highlighting lines fails in remote debugging session](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188844), but it's for PHP, I'm not sure what is "path mapping" for java + weblogic.

**Resolution:**
It turned out that the project source (Project Properties -> Sources) was not correctly configured. The project contains multiple sub modules thus the source path of the sub modules are incorrect. Resolution is to load the sub module as separate projects.